# Cross-thread operation not valid when Thread start

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a method

```
    public void splitXmlFile()
    {
        string[] line = Regex.Split(inputText.Text, "\n+");
        progressStt.Maximum = line.Length;
        progressStt.Step = 1;
        foreach (string q in line)
        {
            progressStt.performStep();
            if (Regex.IsMatch(q, "<[^>]*>"))
            {
                if (Regex.IsMatch(Regex.Split(q, "<[^>]*>")[0], @"\s"))
                {
                }
                string[] gettag = Regex.Split(q, "(<.*?>)|(.+?(?=<|$))");
                foreach (var gettag1 in gettag)
                {
                    if (Regex.IsMatch(gettag1, "<[^>]*>"))
                    {
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (Regex.IsMatch(gettag1, @"\w"))
                            listXml.Add(gettag1);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (Regex.IsMatch(q, @"\w"))
                    listXml.Add(q);
            }
        }
        progressStt.Value = 0;
    }
```

Create new thread:

> Thread t1= new Thread(new ThreadStart(splitXmlFile)); t1.Start();

But when i start i had i exception in line:

```
string[] line = Regex.Split(inputText.Text, "\n+");
```

I think it can come in:

```
progressStt.Maximum = line.Length;
            progressStt.Step = 1;
progressStt.performStep();
progressStt.Value = 0;
```

I can't fix it's, What should i do??

Comment: Don't do that.  You should use an XML parser.

Comment: You should probably use an XML parser instead of half-assing your own.  There are at least a dozen things you'll miss trying to do this with regexes alone.

Comment: There are **hundreds** of questions about this exception message.  No point in adding another one, put the message text in the Search box or use Google.

Comment: InvalidOperationException was unhandled: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'inputText' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

Comment: What are you trying to do?....I love regex, but I think this can be done in a more effective way.

Answer (score 0):

`inputText.Text` resides on the GUI thread. You need to pass in that data *before* the thread starts such as:

```
 newThread.Start(inputText.Text);
```

and then getting the value within the threading method. See MSDN [Thread.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x4c42hc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

I ran into similar and wrote an article on it entitled [C# WPF: Linq Fails in BackgroundWorker DoWork Event](http://omegacoder.com/?p=636)